# Collectd cpu plugin Invalid value for type disk_io_time

Tags: collectd

I am using collectd cpu plugin and collecting the logs messages using logstash. I in logstash I see following error, anyone knows how to fix it?

```
{:timestamp=>"2016-07-15T21:03:53.481000+0000", :message=>"Invalid value for type=\"disk_io_time\", key=nil, index=1", :level=>:error}
{:timestamp=>"2016-07-15T21:03:53.482000+0000", :message=>"Invalid value for type=\"disk_io_time\", key=nil, index=0", :level=>:error}
{:timestamp=>"2016-07-15T21:03:53.482000+0000", :message=>"Invalid value for type=\"disk_io_time\", key=nil, index=1", :level=>:error}
{:timestamp=>"2016-07-15T21:03:53.483000+0000", :message=>"Invalid value for type=\"disk_io_time\", key=nil, index=0", :level=>:error}
{:timestamp=>"2016-07-15T21:03:53.484000+0000", :message=>"Invalid value for type=\"disk_io_time\", key=nil, index=1", :level=>:error}
```

my collectd version - 5.5.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [logstash collectd documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-codecs-collectd.html#plugins-codecs-collectd-typesdb):

> If no types.db is provided the included `types.db` will be used (currently 5.4.0)

It seems there were some changes in collectd 5.5.1 (see [here](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-codec-collectd/issues/21)). Therefore, you need to explicitly set the types.db, for example:

```
input {
  udp {
    codec => collectd {
      typesdb => [ '/usr/share/collectd/types.db']
    }
  }
}
```

See https://collectd.org/documentation/manpages/types.db.5.shtml in order to determine the location of types.db in your installation.